# swift UserDefaults dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

In code I have button and  labels
I want catch text from labels to UserDefaults, but when I press -> in console print "nil"

btn code:

```
@IBAction func tapAddBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let def = UserDefaults.standard

        var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]]
        maAr?.append(["name": self.nameLbl.text, "price": self.costLbl.text, "qty": self.quantNumberLabel.text])
        def.set(maAr, forKey: "cartt")
        def.synchronize()
        print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cartt"))
```

Comment: *Hint:* You never assign a non-nil value to `maAr`

Comment: And please don't use `.synchronize()` it's obsolete.

Comment: So how can I do this?

Comment: add default value of empty array for the nil case. look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time through this method, there is a chance that the array with the key "cartt" is `nil` when retrieved from `UserDefaults`. So if that's the case, then you need to initialize the value with an array.

```
let newValues = ["name": self.nameLbl.text, "price": self.costLbl.text, "qty": self.quantNumberLabel.text]
var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]]
if maAr == nil {
    maAr = [newValues]
} else {
    maAr?.append(newValues)
}
def.set(maAr, forKey: "cartt")
print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cartt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default value to `maAr`:

```
var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()
```

Else, when you click on the button, `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt")` did not set yet, therefore `maAr` get `nil`.

After, `maAr?` does not append anything because the optional chaining failed.

Finally, in `def.set(maAr, forKey: "cartt")` you assign `nil` back to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: `var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []`

Comment: There is no optional chaining in your code. What you have is a conditional cast and the nil coalescing operator providing a default value in case of failure

Comment: I refered to the optional chaining in Bogdan59's code: `maAr?.append(["name": self.nameLbl.text, "price": self.costLbl.text, "qty": self.quantNumberLabel.text])`